# how do I use value of input element in a new file (GET method)

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php
// code that connects to database
?>
<table>

    <form method="get" action="processorder.php">
            <?php
            while (list($pizzaId, $pizzaName, $pizzaNumber, $pizzaPrice) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat))
                    {

                        echo           "<tr>
                                    <td>".$pizzaName."</td>
                                    <td>".$pizzaNumber."</td>
                                    <td>".$pizzaPrice."</td> 
                                    <td> <input type='text' name='$pizzaId' value='$qty' size='3' /></td>
                                    </tr>";
                    }
            mysql_close($db);        
            ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Order now" />
```

I would like to display the pizzas of where there is a value in the input element. 
the processorder.php file would look like:
my url shows the pizzaId's with the values after the '='. So I figured I have an associative array on my hands. 
I thought I'd put a foreach loop in my processorder.php going like

```
   foreach ($_GET['pizzaId'] as $pizza => $qty)    
            {
                echo $pizza." ".$qty."<br />";
            }
```

Yet, when I use the foreach loop, the error in my browser says that the argument of my foreach loop is invalid because $_GET['pizzaId'] isn't an array to begin with (I checked with is_array).
So how do I get access to those values in my value attribute of the input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $pizzaId is an integer.
I would change the name of the input elements to name="pizzas[$pizzaId]", and then you could access it through PHP like this:

```
foreach ($_GET["pizzas"] as $pizzaId => $pizzaQty) {
    echo "$pizzaId $pizzaQty<br />";
}
```

with this method, instead of just plain name="pizzas[]", you also retain the association with the actual pizzaId.

Comment: these type of square brackets in my name attribute make the URL go like http://localhost/pizzashop/bestelling_verw.php?16010%5B%5D=4&16011%5B%5D=4&16012%5B%5D=4&16020%5B%5D=4&16021%5B%5D=4

Comment: @the_visit: that's because you're using the GET method, which will append the parameters to the URL. You can switch to POST (in the HTML FORM tag) and also change the $_GET in the foreach() to $_POST.

Comment: @ Dvir Azulay: changing it to the post array doesn't change the situation, still I have no access to the values.

Comment: @the_visit: On the receiving script (processorder.php) you can use var_dump($_GET,$_POST);die; and see how the data is structured in order to learn how to handle it

Comment: YES that helped. I got the values displayed now. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put an array into $_GET then your url should look like:

```
//site/page?pizzaID[]=123&pizzaID[]=124
```

You can achive this with similar usage of `name` of input field

```
<input name="pizzaID[]" />
<input name="pizzaID[]" />
```

Comment: Here also, the square brackets don't get passed as square brackets in my url, but with `%`sings and the number 5. What's going on here?

Comment: this is another question and you should open a new question :) (it could be because you have some purifier before your output)